# In PostgreSQL, is there a CLI command to copy the speed of a SELECT statement as well as the SELECT statement into a text file (without the data)?

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface, psql

I am currently comparing performance of PostgreSQL with several other SQL systems. I am aware of the `\timing` option to turn on timing queries. However, I would very much like to automate the process of copying the statements executed and the query speed below it. I imagine there is a simple way to log this?

Let's say I run:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT itemID, prodCategory
FROM products
WHERE prodCategory = "footwear"
```

I want to automatically save into a text file:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT itemID, prodCategory
FROM products
WHERE prodCategory = "footwear"

SELECT 7790
Time: 10.884 ms
```

If OS Specifications are needed, I am using MacOS.

Comment: You could use `explain analyze` and the save the output of _that_

Comment: Wouldn't that add overhead to the query, thereby defeating the purpose of performance testing? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that you can use the:

> script *filename*

command to save everything that is printed on your screen. If timing is on, you can record the queries and the query time outputs.

To stop recording, simply type `exit`.